# Loop with .each method on ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

I have a doubt, i have a .each loop like this:

```
mayor = @lt[1][1]
@lt.each do |item|
  if item[1] > mayor then
    mayor = item[1]
  end
end
```

That loop started in the first item of the array `@lt` but instead i want it to start by the second item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@lt[1..-1].each do |item|
  # Do things with item
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that @lt is an `Enumerable` (Array, Hash, or similar), you can use [`drop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop) to skip any number of items from the start:

```
@lt.drop(1).each do |item|
...
end
```

Comment: I'm always amazed when someone comes up with a built-in method that I haven't encountered before, especially on something like Enumerable. Love it!

Answer (score 0):

```
@lt[1..(@lt.length-1)].each { |item|
   # Do something
}
```